# Implementing saveAs.js in Aurelia webmap to save canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, aurelia, savefiledialog

Hi I'm very new to this and can't find a way to implement saveAs.js in Aurelia webmap to save canvas as in this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html). It Works in Edge but not in Chrome. I have installed the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) as per instructions and import it in my map file as

```
import { saveAs } from 'FileSaver';
```

When i test the app with gulp watch the Chrome returns: Uncaught TypeError: saveAs is not a function
    at eval (map.js:317)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved using  tag wtth data string.